# Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform. (something wrong with StreamBuilder)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Getting error please see the image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfjE0.png)

**Error code**

*The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#92e48):
Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform*

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _store.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                builder: (context ,snapshot){
                  if(!snapshot.hasData){
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                  List<Text> messagesWidgets =[];
                  for(var message in messages){
                    final messageID = message['id'];
                    final messageText = message['text'];
                    final messagesWidget = Text('$messageID from $messageText');
                    messagesWidgets.add(messagesWidget);
                  }
                  return
                      Column(
                        children : messagesWidgets,

                      );
                }
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also happen by passing wrong attribute name that does not exist in the document, while displaying document data in a builder method. This solved the issue for me.

and also you can try to print `messages` in console and then assign in loop.